# C# нуль-терминированная строка из обычной?

Tags: c#

Здравствуйте.

Есть простая строка Пусть будет такая: "Test message", её байты выглядят так: 54 65 73 74 20 6D 65 73 73 61 67 65

Мне нужно из неё сделать нуль-терминированную строку, у которой байты выглядят так: 54 00 65 00 73 00 74 00 20 00 6D 00 65 00 73 00 73 00 61 00 67 00 65 00 00 00

В дельфи это зовется WideString.

Можно это сделать, конечно, в цикле, но это будет ужасный код.

Подскажите, как можно нативными методами сделать такое преобразование.

Спасибо.

Comment: А почему нет 00 54 и 65, например?

Comment: Извиняюсь, опечатка, забыл вручную их добавить. терминаторы добавлял руками, не копипастом.

Comment: Воспользовался советом уважаемого @VladD и сделал буфер листом байтов. Так же воспользовался его же советом по конвертации в юникод. Теперь код работает идеально и красиво. Спасибо.

Comment: @Евгений Карпов: пожалуйста!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В .NET строка — абстрактное понятие, для того, чтобы превратить её в байты, нужно указать кодировку.

Делайте [так](http://ideone.com/s2Q4m4):

```
var utf16 = Encoding.Unicode;
var s = "Test message";
var bytes = utf16.GetBytes(s);
```

Ноль в конце придётся дописать вручную.

Не забывайте, однако, что строки в .NET могут содержать нулевой символ в середине, так что корректная конвертация не всегда возможна. Это может иметь последствия для безопасности пользователей вашего приложения. ([Пример](http://www.mozilla.org/security/announce/2007/mfsa2007-07.html).)

---

Если такая строка нужна вам для interop-сценариев, приведение строки к нужному виду сделает за вас компилятор. Смотрите в сторону атрибута [`[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWSTR)]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s9ts558h%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Превращаю строку в массив байтов и отсылаю сокетом. Сервер выводит саму строку и её хекс-последовательность. Если делать нечто вроде string s = "some text" - то строка не нультерминированная. Гарантировать, что строки всегда будут создаваться в нужной кодировке я не могу (плагины, скрипты). Поэтому мне нужна принудительная конвертация строки в юникод. Сейчас использую такой вот костыль: _buffer.Append(Encoding.Unicode.GetString(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(s+"\0"))); но мне он кажется ужасным и пугает меня. Есть ли более правильный способ конвертации любой строки в юникод?

Comment: Такая строка мне нужна для отправки в составе сетевого пакета, чтобы можно было её "отпарсить" по шаблону.

Comment: А что вам кажется неправильным в вашем методе? Я бы написал просто

    _buffer.AddRange(utf16.GetBytes(s + "\0"));

поскольку, если уж вы опускаетесь на уровень кодировки, буфер должен быть массивом байт, а не строкой.

Comment: Старая привычка из дельфи работать со строкой как с массивом для байтов... Ни чего не могу с собой поделать. За код спасибо большое, сейчас испробую.

Comment: Не понял для какого типа использован метод AddRange? Я на данный момент использую StringBuilder. Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Строку использовать как буфер не стоит. Например, в Microsoft'овской реализации строки внутри UTF16, а в Mono — UTF32.

Comment: @Евгений Карпов: для `List<byte>`, конечно. `StringBuilder` плох по той же причине, что и `string`.

Answer (score 2):

Простите, а с чего вы взяли, что ваша строка будет храниться без нулей? В C# полная поддержка Unicode, а следовательно, строки там  состоят из двухбайтных символов (впрочем, тут не все так просто, насколько я помню - символ юникода не обязательно состоит из 16 битов). Всяческие ухищрения со строками в Delphi. если я не ошибаюсь, еще с тех времен, когда этот язык не поддерживал Unicode (а случилось это знаменательное событие, по-моему, аж в 2009 году). Так вот Если в Delphi для получения интересующего вас результата надо воспользоваться WideString, то в C# это есть по умолчанию. 
Ради эксперимента попробуйте вот что и посмотрите результат:

```
string s = "qwerty";
var bytes = new byte[s.Length * sizeof(char)];
Buffer.BlockCopy(s.ToCharArray(), 0, bytes, 0, bytes.Length);

foreach(byte t in bytes)
    Console.Write("{0} ", t);
```

И кстати, нуль-терминированная строка - это кое что [другое](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null-terminated_string)
З.Ы. по строкам в .NET не далее как вчера была вот [эта](http://habrahabr.ru/post/172627/) статья

Comment: Коментарий добавил чуть ниже. Я знаю что такое нуль-терминированная строка - это строка, все чары в которой разделены нулями (0x00), а так же присутствует завершающий нулевой чар (так же терминированный нулем).

Comment: Это справедливо только для ASCII-подмножества. Для символов кириллицы там не ноль: http://ideone.com/wD2gV6

Comment: >Я знаю что такое нуль-терминированная строка - это строка, все чары в которой разделены нулями

Где вы это вычитали? Насколько мне известно:
1) Нуль-терминированные строки содержат нулевой символ в конце. Именно по этому символу определяется длина строки и, собственно, ее конец. Будь верно то, о чем вы пишете, определение длины по нулевому символу было бы бессмысленно
2) Цитата из википедии: "Null-terminated strings require of the encoding that it does not use the 0x00 value for any character"

3) само название говорит о том, что это строки, ЗАВЕРШАЕМЫЕ нулем

Поправьте, если ошибаюсь

Comment: Хорошо, не ноль, а 04 (или другой терминатор, точнее добавочный чар). Но заканчивается строка в любом случае нулем, терминированным нулем (\x00\x00). Это и нужно, чтобы смело распознать конец строки. Ну, а если пользователь отправит нуль в середине строки - это уже его проблема, как мог я помог, и в документации это укажу.

Comment: >Но заканчивается строка в любом случае нулем, терминированным нулем (\x00\x00)

разве не именно это я вам и утверждал?

Comment: Хм, да, я немного недоучил теорию на эту тему... Разумеется, Вы правы. И терминатор - это символ завершения строки.

Comment: это следует хотя бы из названия - to terminate = прекращать (завершать)